# LINQ Query for sum and aggregate data

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have two model classes of which I have provided the sql table structure

```sql
CREATE TABLE [DBO].[TBL_PRODUCTION] ( -- class ProductionModel
     PRODUCTION_ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL  
    ,PRODUCTION_NAME NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
    ,PRODUCTION_TYPE INT NOT NULL
    ,PRODUCTION_QUANTITY INT
    ,CONSTRAINT PK_PRODUCTION PRIMARY KEY (PRODUCTION_ID)
    )
INSERT INTO [DBO].[TBL_PRODUCTION] VALUES ('SGU',1, 100)
INSERT INTO [DBO].[TBL_PRODUCTION] VALUES ('BGU',1, 100)
INSERT INTO [DBO].[TBL_PRODUCTION] VALUES ('CCGU',2, 150)

CREATE TABLE [DBO].[TBL_DISTRIBUTOR] ( class DistributorModel
     DISTRIBUTOR_ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL
    ,PRODUCTION_ID INT NOT NULL 
    ,QUARTER_TYPE INT NOT NULL
    ,DEMAND_QUANTITY INT    
    ,CONSTRAINT PK_DISTRIBUTOR PRIMARY KEY (DISTRIBUTOR_ID)
    )
INSERT INTO [DBO].[TBL_DISTRIBUTOR] VALUES (1,555,1,25)
INSERT INTO [DBO].[TBL_DISTRIBUTOR] VALUES (1,555,2,25)
INSERT INTO [DBO].[TBL_DISTRIBUTOR] VALUES (1,655,3,25)
INSERT INTO [DBO].[TBL_DISTRIBUTOR] VALUES (2,555,1,25)
INSERT INTO [DBO].[TBL_DISTRIBUTOR] VALUES (2,745,2,25)
INSERT INTO [DBO].[TBL_DISTRIBUTOR] VALUES (3,745,3,25)
INSERT INTO [DBO].[TBL_DISTRIBUTOR] VALUES (1,745,3,10)
INSERT INTO [DBO].[TBL_DISTRIBUTOR] VALUES (2,745,3,50)
```

I need to show data about total distribution on quarterly basis. I mean how many total productions are distributed in each quarter and the remaining production quantity. I have made the `sql query` but how to design `LINQ` query for the same. I have excluded the `remaining quantity` in SQL Query but need to show in `LINQ` Query.

**SQL Query**

```sql
SELECT 
A.PRODUCTION_ID 
,B.PRODUCTION_NAME
,A.QUARTER_TYPE 
,B.PRODUCTION_QUANTITY
,SUM(A.DEMAND_QUANTITY) [TOTAL DISTRIBUTED]
FROM [DBO].[TBL_DISTRIBUTOR] A
INNER JOIN [DBO].[TBL_PRODUCTION] B ON A.PRODUCTION_ID = B.PRODUCTION_ID
GROUP BY
A.PRODUCTION_ID  
,B.PRODUCTION_NAME
,B.PRODUCTION_QUANTITY
,A.QUARTER_TYPE 
ORDER BY A.PRODUCTION_ID
```

I am just learning LINQ query so do not have idea how to express this in sql query in LINQ. I have the POCO Class too, now how to proceed further.

```cs
public class DistributorViewModels
{
    public int PRODUCTION_ID { get; set; }
    public string PRODUCTION_NAME { get; set; }
    public int QUARTER_TYPE { get; set; }
    public int PRODUCTION_QUANTITY { get; set; }
    public int TOTAL_DISTRIBUTED { get; set; }
    public int REMAINING_QUANTITY { get; set; }
}
```

Please see the attached image for what is my desired output.

Hoping for positive response. Thank You to all!!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

firstly some thoughts:
Does it make sense to group by production quanitity?
Also does it make sense to group by production name if you have already grouped by production id?

Based on those thoughts I would created following linq statements (the beginning is only data from your desired output):

```
List<DISTRIBUTOR> tbl_distribution = new List<DISTRIBUTOR>(){
    new DISTRIBUTOR{PRODUCTION_ID = 1, QUARTER_TYPE = 1, DEMAND_QUANTITY = 15},
    new DISTRIBUTOR{PRODUCTION_ID = 1, QUARTER_TYPE = 1, DEMAND_QUANTITY = 10},
    new DISTRIBUTOR{PRODUCTION_ID = 1, QUARTER_TYPE = 2, DEMAND_QUANTITY = 25},
    new DISTRIBUTOR{PRODUCTION_ID = 1, QUARTER_TYPE = 3, DEMAND_QUANTITY = 35},
    new DISTRIBUTOR{PRODUCTION_ID = 2, QUARTER_TYPE = 1, DEMAND_QUANTITY = 25},
    new DISTRIBUTOR{PRODUCTION_ID = 2, QUARTER_TYPE = 2, DEMAND_QUANTITY = 25},
    new DISTRIBUTOR{PRODUCTION_ID = 2, QUARTER_TYPE = 3, DEMAND_QUANTITY = 50},
    new DISTRIBUTOR{PRODUCTION_ID = 3, QUARTER_TYPE = 3, DEMAND_QUANTITY = 25},
};


List<PRODUCTION> tbl_production = new List<PRODUCTION>{
    new PRODUCTION{ PRODUCTION_ID = 1, PRODUCTION_NAME = "SGU", PRODUCTION_QUANTITY = 100},
    new PRODUCTION{ PRODUCTION_ID = 2, PRODUCTION_NAME = "BGU", PRODUCTION_QUANTITY = 100},
    new PRODUCTION{ PRODUCTION_ID = 3, PRODUCTION_NAME = "CCGU", PRODUCTION_QUANTITY = 150}, 
};

var temp = from a in tbl_distribution
            join b in tbl_production on a.PRODUCTION_ID equals b.PRODUCTION_ID
            let totalProductDistributed = tbl_distribution.Where(t => t.PRODUCTION_ID == a.PRODUCTION_ID ).Sum(t => t.DEMAND_QUANTITY)
            select new {
                PRODUCTION_ID = a.PRODUCTION_ID,
                PRODUCTION_NAME = b.PRODUCTION_NAME,
                QUARTER_TYPE = a.QUARTER_TYPE,
                PRODUCTION_QUANTITY = b.PRODUCTION_QUANTITY,
                TOTAL_DISTRIBUTED = totalProductDistributed,
                REMAINING_QUANTITY = b.PRODUCTION_QUANTITY - totalProductDistributed 
            };
                                    
var ViewModel = from s in temp group s by new{s.PRODUCTION_ID, s.QUARTER_TYPE} into g
select  g.FirstOrDefault();
```

But you can also group by production id and have a table of quarterly infos. That would be just a single linq statement and you can achive your "merged" rows in one column:

```
var ViewModel2 = from a in tbl_distribution group a by a.PRODUCTION_ID into g
           join b in tbl_production on g.FirstOrDefault().PRODUCTION_ID equals b.PRODUCTION_ID

            let quarterInfos = from c in g
                               group c by c.QUARTER_TYPE into d
                               select new
                               {
                                   Quarter = d.FirstOrDefault().QUARTER_TYPE,
                                   DemandQuantity = d.Sum(t => t.DEMAND_QUANTITY),
                               }

            select new{
                g.Key,
                b.PRODUCTION_NAME,
                b.PRODUCTION_QUANTITY,
                QuarterInfos = quarterInfos,
                RemainingQuantity = b.PRODUCTION_QUANTITY - quarterInfos.Sum(i => i.DemandQuantity)
            };
```